# Why can I pass a String and a StringBuilder references to the '+' opereator, but not other objects

Tags: java, string, class, object, operators

I have a Person object.If I try to pass this object along with a reference to an Integer wrapper class to the '+' operator, I get an error because they arent of the same dataype. But if I have a String and a StringBuilder references. Each reference points to a valid value and I pass this to the + operator, it prints the concatenated value.My question is arent String and StringBuilder 2 DIFFERENT classes? (Just like Person and Integer), why am i not getting the compiler error in this case?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Double d1=new Double(23);
        Integer i1=new Integer(5);

      //  System.out.println(new Pers()+d1);//compiler error
        System.out.println(new StringBuilder("abc")+ new String("zyz"));
    }
}
```

I am trying to understand these strange things happening in the language and want to be a better programmer. Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: what result would you expect from new Pers() + d1; ?

Comment: Because the string concatenation operator is a thing: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1 - but you cannot just pass anything to `+`. Btw: are you *sure* you can `+` `StringBuilder`s?

Comment: Also, consider "3.0 + 4" (float and integer)

Comment: @Stultuske have mentioned in the question new Pers() +d1 results it compiler error

Comment: @Anil no, that is the actual result, and a logical one at that. What was the one you expected?

Comment: @luk2302 yes .Have tested by passing a String and a String Builder, it works normally printing "abcxyz". Also thank you for the docs link, I was really not getting the right words to google this issue

Comment: @Stultuske i expected a compiler error too because Double and Person are 2 different datatypes. Hence i was expecting the same for string and StringBuilder.

Comment: @Anil what makes you assume that's because they are of different datatypes?

Comment: @Stultuske are you saying that since they both extend Object class? is my sentence "Double and Person are 2 different datatypes" wrong? Please correct me

Comment: "hello " + 1 -> this will compile and work, even though they're not both the same data type, and one of them is not an Object. No, I mean it when certain types are involved.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that the string concatenation operator `+` kicks in only if atleast one of the operands is a `CharSequence`, which `String` and `StringBuilder` are. If there is no `CharSequence`, the attempt is to perform an actual addition.

When you give `Pers` and `Double`, the compiler is not able to guess that you want string concatenation. It is first trying to compute the value of the operation and then trying to convert to string.

So, `"" + new Pers() + d1` will work.